# Which design pattern should be used if same input comes from different data sources and final object is exactly the same

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to create an object where input can come from different data sources and final object created is of same class type. For instance

Input source (constructor argument) can either be: 
    1. file path as string
    2. content as string

Note: Data type for both is same which is String.

Which design patter should I use?

I am thinking of using "Simple Factory" and add the methods:

```
ClassA fromFilePath(String){}
ClassA fromContent(String){}
```

However not sure where to put the logic to load/process the content from input source to create/initialise the instance.

Please advise.

Comment: Have you had a look at builder? https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder

Comment: Also check out https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Factory` fits to your problem:

```
interface IInputParser {
    ClassA Parse(string input);
}

class ContentParser implements IInputParser {
    public ClassA Parse(string input) {
        // create object from content
    }
}

class FileParser implements IInputParser {
    public ClassA Parse(string input) {
        // create object from file
    }
}

class ParserFactory {
    public IInputParser GetParser(string input) {
        if (IsPath(input))
            return new FileParser();
        else
            return new ContentParser();
    }

    boolean IsPath(string input) {
        // returns true if input is a file path
    }
}
```

Even in this case you can also think about `Chain of Responsibility` but I personally prefer `Factory`